# getting random number from a prime list in python

Tags: python

guys i am totally new to programming in python so i need your help please ... i want to generate a prime number from a prime list i have created ... here is my code

```
list = []
for i in range(2,15):
primeflag=True
for num in list:
    if(i%num==0):
        primeflag=False
if(primeflag):
    list.append(i)
    a = random.choice(list)
print list , a

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

it gives me an error 
so any help ??
thanks in advance

Comment: Print your import, the problem is maybe there.

Answer (score 4):

Use `import random` instead of `from random import random`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @zero323's answer, if you don't need more than `choice` function, you can do this instead:

```
from random import choice
```

And use it straight away:

```
a = choice(list)
```

Also your program might not do what you wanted. Currently, if you find `5` in your list, you will add a new `5` to the list.

Tips: Never use `list` as a variable name! It will override the built-in function with the same name, `list`.