# invalid syntax in printing prime lists in python

Tags: python

quys i am totally new to programming so please help me ... i am trying to make a function produce all the prime numbers and put it in list and generate a ranodm number from this list ... here is my code

```
from random import choice
question_3():
    list = []
    for i in range(2,20):
        flag=True
        for num in list:
            if(i%num==0):
                flag=False
        if(flag):
            list.append(i)
            p = choice(list)
        print list , p 

question_3()
```

but an error appeared

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you haven't defined the function properly

Comment: I see you've used the import as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752593/getting-random-number-from-a-prime-list-in-python - but may I suggest when getting these errors to not immediately post them to SO, and instead look at where the interpreter is pointing you to and using a search engine and taking a few minutes to see if there's anything immediately obvious. If there's not, then when you post, say what you've looked for and why you still don't understand the error...

Comment: Don't use `list` as the name for a variable, since there is already a built-in `list()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `def` before the function name:

```
def question_3():
    for i in range(2,20):
        #...
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `def` before the definition of the function `question_3`.

Some additional comments: Please get rid of the unnecessary parens when you use an if-statement and don't use `list` as a variable name because you shadow the builtin [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

Reading [PEP-8, the Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import choice

def question_3():
    list = []
    for i in range(2,20):
        flag=True
        for num in list:
            if(i%num==0):
                flag=False
        if(flag):
            list.append(i)
            p = choice(list)
        print list , p 

question_3()
```